# draw in the space left unused by BoxLayout

Tags: kivy

I want to make GUI which allows me to enter text at the bottom and also allow me to draw in the remainder of the screen .I was able to make the textbox and button at the bottom of the window using BoxLayout, but i am not able to use the remaining space for drawing. Here is the output of my code:[The output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YWIWC.jpg)

And the below is my code

```
import sys
import os
import kivy
kivy.require("1.10.0")
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.graphics import Line,Ellipse
from kivy.config import Config

Config.set('input', 'mouse', 'mouse,multitouch_on_demand')

class Draw(Widget):
    def on_touch_down(self,touch):
        print(touch)
        with self.canvas:
            touch.ud["line"]=Line(points=(touch.x,touch.y))
    def on_touch_move(self,touch):
        print(touch)
        with self.canvas:
            touch.ud["line"].points +=(touch.x,touch.y)
    def on_touch_up(self,touch):
        print("released mouse",touch)


class MAP(BoxLayout):    
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MAP, self).__init__(**kwargs)        
        self.S=TextInput(multiline=False, size_hint=(800,0.05))
        self.add_widget(self.S)
        self.b=Button(text="OK",size_hint=(200,0.05))
        self.add_widget(self.b)
    Draw()






class GUI(App):
    def build(self):
        return MAP()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(Window.size)
    GUI().run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Draw` widget does the drawing, but it is never added to the display. Try changing your `MAP` class to:

```
class MAP(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MAP, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.S=TextInput(multiline=False, size_hint=(800,0.05))
        self.add_widget(self.S)
        self.b=Button(text="OK",size_hint=(200,0.05))
        self.add_widget(self.b)
        self.draw = Draw()
        self.add_widget(self.draw)
   # Draw()
```

Note that the stray `Draw()` is commented out (it was not doing anything) and a `Draw` widget is now added to the `MAP` widget.

Comment: Great! it works . I understood now that we need to instantiate an object of class and assign it to the widget